# Debugging a DLL from VS2008 in VC6

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, dll, visual-c++-6, pdb-files

I am currently debugging a project in VC6 (slowly porting it over to VS2008). The project  links to a DLL that I have produced in VS2008 with a Debug build. (I know - a strange situation to find myself in.)
I need to debug the project in VC6 and step into the calls to the DLL.
Even though I have the PDB alongside the DLL, VC6 still reports there is no symbolic info for the DLL when it loads it. 
Does anyone know why? Is the PDB from VS2008 not loadable by VC6? 
Any ideas gratefully received...

Answer (score 1):

The short answer you can't. The PDBs are not backwards compatible with earlier version of Visual studio.